# how to add sweetalert depends on children exists or not

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am new to javascript. I want show sweetalert if only children is exist. I have a container, if I add something into it and I try to navigate to other page without saving then sweetalert should popup and ask whether save or leave.

After many iteration my code is

```
jQuery(document).click(function(e) {
    if(document.getElementById($scope.mainContainerId).children().length>0) {
        if (jQuery(e.target).is('a')) {
            e.preventDefault();

                swal({
                    title: "Are you sure?",
                    text: "Want to continue without saving?",
                    type: "warning",
                    showCancelButton: true,
                    confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
                    confirmButtonText: "Leave",
                    closeOnConfirm: false,
                    html: false
                },

                function(isConfirm) {
                    if (isConfirm) {
                        window.location = jQuery(e.target).attr('href');
                    }
                });
            }


     };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`<element>.children` is not a function, so adding parentheses should be throwing an error.  As a result, this if condition will not evaluate to true.

```
if(document.getElementById($scope.mainContainerId).children().length>0) {}
```

To fix it, you should be able to simply remove the parentheses after `children`.

```
jQuery(document).click(function(e) {
  if(document.getElementById($scope.mainContainerId).children.length>0) {
    if (jQuery(e.target).is('a')) {
      e.preventDefault();

      swal({
        title: "Are you sure?",
        text: "Want to continue without saving?",
        type: "warning",
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
        confirmButtonText: "Leave",
        closeOnConfirm: false,
        html: false
      },
        function(isConfirm) {
          if (isConfirm) {
            window.location = jQuery(e.target).attr('href');
          }
      });
    }
  }
});
```